# How to implement android tutorial slider

Tags: java, android, slider

My question is how to implement such kind of slider(.

Illustration:

[image]

So many views to use: `<ViewPager>`, `<RecycleLayout>`, `<GridLayout>`, `<LinearLayout>`, etc. But which from those I need to choose?

I know that there will be fixed number of sections, each section should have active state, and should be triggered by outer event(next/prev buttons for e.g.), and then previous section receive disabled state. 
Also user should be able to scroll slider by swiping on it to look how many steps there and what they are, but section should not change it's state(not moving to next step, without finishing previous)

I'm new to androiddev.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, *software library* (e.g. Pager, Layout, ...), tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the sources of these libraries

https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding-android

https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen